# Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"foo"'

Tags: typescript

I have this code:

```
const baseUpstreamImpl = (
  client: IClient,
): ProtocolExtension<
  {
    foobar: (buff: Buffer) => Promise<string>;
  }
> => ({
  name: 'base upstream impl',
  type: 'upstream',
  messageCreators: {
    foobar: (buff: Buffer)  =>
      Promise.resolve({
        type: 'foobar',
        payload: buff,
      }),
  },
});
```

This . is the error I get for the foobar function:

```
[ts]
Type '(buff: Buffer) => Promise<{ type: string; payload: Buffer; }>' is not assignable to type '(...args: any[]) => Promise<IMessage<{ foobar: (buff: Buffer) => Promise<string>; }, "foobar">>'.
  Type 'Promise<{ type: string; payload: Buffer; }>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<IMessage<{ foobar: (buff: Buffer) => Promise<string>; }, "foobar">>'.
    Type '{ type: string; payload: Buffer; }' is not assignable to type 'IMessage<{ foobar: (buff: Buffer) => Promise<string>; }, "foobar">'.
      Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"foobar"'.
baseUpstreamImpl.ts(11, 5): The expected type comes from property 'foobar' which is declared here on type '{ foobar: (...args: any[]) => Promise<IMessage<{ foobar: (buff: Buffer) => Promise<string>; }, "foobar">>; }'
(property) foobar: (...args: any[]) => Promise<IMessage<{
    foobar: (buff: Buffer) => Promise<string>;
}, "foobar">>
```

And here are my types:

```
type EnforcePromise<T, P = any> = T extends Promise<P> ? T : Promise<T>;

type Promised<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: (...args: InferArgs<T[P]>) => EnforcePromise<InferType<T[P]>>
};

type Filter<T, Cond, U extends keyof T = keyof T> = {
  [K in U]: T[K] extends Cond ? K : never
}[U];

type EventKey<T> = Filter<T, (...args: any[]) => any>;


interface IMessage<T, K extends EventKey<T> = EventKey<T>> {
  type: K;
  payload: InferArgs<T[K]>;
}


export interface ProtocolExtension<T, U, R = {}> {
  name: string;
  type: 'upstream' | 'downstream';
  handlers: Promised<T>;
  messageCreators: {
    [K in keyof U]: (
      ...args: any[]
    ) => Promise<IMessage<U>>
  };
}
```

Comment: You did not post `InferArgs`

Comment: It's like `T extends (...args: infer R) => any ? R : never`

Comment: I added the missing types, still can't get your error, since I get `Generic type 'ProtocolExtension<T, U, R>' requires between 2 and 3 type arguments.`  (which is true) could you update your question with a snippet that reproduces your issue ?

Comment: Here you go bit.ly/2Qy2NiE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in the code both related to the way typescript infers types for literals.

The first one (and the error message you have) is the fact that `type: 'foobar'` will infer `type` to be `string` (in the absence of an imediate reason to infer it to the string literal type `'foobar'`). The solution to this is to use a type assertion to the string literal type manually.

After we fix this issue we have a new error on the payload. `payload` should be `InferArgs<T[K]>` so it should be tuple with the parameter of the function. You only assign a single value to it. If we were to write `[buf]` we would have a similar problem to the string literal type issue above. Namely array literal would be typed as an array not a tuple (again in the absence of an imediate reason to type it as a tuple type).

There is also a third issue, the absence of the `handelrs`  property, but taht is probably just an oversight.

```
const baseUpstreamImpl = (
    client: {},
): ProtocolExtension<
{},
{
    foobar: (buff: {}) => Promise<string>;
}
> => ({
    name: 'base upstream impl',
    type: 'upstream',
    handlers: null as any,
    messageCreators: {
        foobar: (buff: {}) =>
            Promise.resolve({
                type: 'foobar' as 'foobar',
                payload: [buff] as [{}],
            }),
    },
});
```

Comment: So the as foobar was what I was missing ^^ typescript can be tricky Thanks !

Comment: @Vinz243 well, I listed all the things I had to do to get it to compile, that is why a snippet that reproduces the problem and is close to your actual code helps :)